# Bit manipulation: changing a single char in the binary "array"

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

For example, if I have

```
long binarynumber=10011;
```

and I want it to do

```
binarynumber=binarynumber>>1;
```

But instead of discarding the rightmost number(the number would be 01001 in 5 digits), I want it to be 11001 where the last number moves to the first place in the binary "string". The value of the binary number doesn't really matter, since I am using it as a string to output.

Comment: 1. Do you know that `long binarynumber=10011` is 10011100011011 in its binary representation. 2. Shoul 1 in `binarynumber=binarynumber>>1;` be treated as constant?

Comment: How do you know where to shift-in the rightmost digit? If you just do it at the numeric level, you'd get `10011` -> `11001` -> `11100` -> `1110` -> `111` -> `111` -> `111` -> `111`, because leading zeroes are not retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about doing something like this

```
public static String circularShiftBinary(long binaryNumber, int shift)
{
    String bin = Long.toString(binaryNumber);
    //check that the shift isn't a fully circular shift
    if(shift % bin.length() != 0)
        while(shift-- > 0)
            bin = bin.charAt(bin.length() - 1) + bin.substring(0, bin.length() - 1);

    return bin;
}
```

Example call for variations

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long binaryNumber = 10011;
    int shift = 0;

    while(shift < 6)
        System.out.println(circularShiftBinary(binaryNumber, shift++));
}//main method
```

Output

```
10011
11001
11100
01110
00111
10011
```

Comment: Replace `new Long(binaryNumber).toString()` with `Long.toString(binaryNumber)`.

Comment: thank you @Andreas, i really didn't want to have to create a new Long object

Comment: What exactly does ' bin = bin.charAt(bin.length() - 1) + bin.substring(0, bin.length() - 1); ' this do and how would I change this code so it shifts the other way?

Comment: @Spano Write a string on a piece of paper, e.g. `Hello`, and pretend that's the value of `bin`. Now manually do on paper what that statement does. Then you'll see, and you'll learn how to change the statement to shift the other way.